# How to DELETE multiple records in postgresql with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i have created a controller that can delete my car recors, but i do not know how to **DELETE MULTIPLE RECORDS** with postgresql. I hope anybody can help me and give me some ideas in order to make this. Below it is my controller but it only delete one, now i wanna make delete multiple records please help me

```
// delete a car
export async function deleteCar(req, res) {
  try {
    const car = await Car.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.car_id);
    if (!car) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
    res.send(car);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Server error. Please try again.",
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
}
```

Model

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export const Car = sequelize.define("car", {
    car_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true, 
      autoIncrement:true,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      required:  [true, 'Car name required'],
    },
    color: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      required: [true, 'Car color required'],
    },
    brand: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      required: [true, 'Car brand required'],
    },
  }, { sequelize, freezeTableName: true}
)

export default Car;
```

Routes

```
router.delete("/cars/:carId", deleteCar);
```

Comment: What module do you use for connecting to PostgresSQL db ?

Comment: i think sequelize

Comment: Read this, you can delete multiple recodes with where function explained in this link https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#simple-delete-queries

Comment: So, you mean use TRUNCATE to delete all

Comment: You can use TRUNCATE if you want to destroy everything on a table. But if you want to delete multiple users with a condition you can use Where option.

Comment: So, could you help me to improve my code. i just wanna know how it looks like

Comment: Please show a model definition and your current Sequelize query for deleting a single car record.

Comment: Edited as you want

Comment: @kato You want to delete multiple record by id, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete multiple record in Sequelize You can use this code instead:

```
// delete a car
export async function deleteCar(req, res) {
  try {
    //multipleIds = req.params.car_ids;
    //you should send array of ids you want to delete in req.params.car_ids 
    //and delete the next line
    
    let multipleIds =  [100, 101, 102, 103]; // You can delete this line later
    const car = await Car.destroy({ where: { id: multipleIds }});
    //this delete cars with id 100, 101, 102, 103 
    if (!car) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
    res.send(car);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Server error. Please try again.",
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
}
```

After you find out how it works You can fill `multipleIds` variable dynamically